# How to install github.com/ioi/isolate on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, c++, g++, github

I recently tried to make a C++ judge and heard about a tool called "Isolate" (available [here](https://github.com/ioi/isolate)):

> Run program within a sandbox, so that it cannot communicate with the outside world and its resource consumption is limited. This can be used for example in a programming contest to run untrusted programs submitted by contestants in a controlled environment.

I'm not quite sure how to install it onto my computer (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04), though, and don't understand the steps from the [user manual](http://www.ucw.cz/moe/isolate.1.html#_installation)'s Installation process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install you need to open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcap-dev asciidoc-base
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/ioi/isolate.git
cd isolate
make
sudo make install
```

Then follow its local help about usage.